# Altering a table an saving it to mariadb mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

First off when inserting my DB i threw an error on one table in particular... the one in question below.. the first error was: Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed << I manually removed a few and it finished inserting the db. When i looked at the db i noticed that table in particular was missing. So now ive added the table manually and.. trying to insert.

Mysql MariaDB having the most difficult time inserting this into a table. The table is already created in the DB and it blank atm. I'm running it through a syntax checker and it keeps puking out this error and i am unfamiliar with this error or do not know how to fix it.

Here is the error:

```
>  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '( `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
> `name` text COM' at line 1
```

Here is the SQL (ALTER TABLE) statement:

```
 ALTER TABLE `customer_grid_flat` (
      `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
      `name` text COMMENT 'Name',
      `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
      `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Group_id',
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created_at',
      `website_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website_id',
      `confirmation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Confirmation',
      `created_in` text COMMENT 'Created_in',
      `dob` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Dob',
      `gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gender',
      `taxvat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Taxvat',
      `lock_expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Lock_expires',
      `customer_discount_group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer_discount_group',
      `net_terms_id` text COMMENT 'Net_terms_id',
      `origin` text COMMENT 'Origin',
      `parent_customer_id` text COMMENT 'Parent_customer_id',
      `shipping_payment_type` text COMMENT 'Shipping_payment_type',
      `target_customer_id` text COMMENT 'Target_customer_id',
      `target_salesperson_id` text COMMENT 'Target_salesperson_id',
      `shipping_full` text COMMENT 'Shipping_full',
      `billing_full` text COMMENT 'Billing_full',
      `billing_firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_firstname',
      `billing_lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_lastname',
      `billing_country_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_country_id',
      `billing_street` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_street',
      `billing_vat_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Billing_vat_id',
      PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GROUP_ID` (`group_id`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CREATED_AT` (`created_at`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_CONFIRMATION` (`confirmation`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_DOB` (`dob`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_GENDER` (`gender`),
      KEY `CUSTOMER_GRID_FLAT_BILLING_COUNTRY_ID` (`billing_country_id`),
      FULLTEXT KEY `FTI_E6952E9D8A6EAABA183A6212F5AE5345` (`name`,`email`,`created_in`,`taxvat`,`origin`,`parent_customer_id`,`shipping_payment_type`,`target_customer_id`,`shipping_full`,`billing_full`,`billing_firstname`,`billing_lastname`)
    );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2  @ysth

Comment: Looks like you have an `ALTER TABLE` command that looks like a `CREATE TABLE` syntax instead. Further down your example, there is a `CREATE TABLE` statement, so maybe it's just that the `ALTER` statement simply needs to be removed?

Comment: i think i accidently pasted that twice. let me fix that

Comment: alter table has a completely different syntax than create table, but you are treating it as if it were the same.  it sounds like you have the table already created; what is it you are trying to change?

Comment: The table is created but has nothing in it.. so i'm trying to insert all the columns

Comment: Tables cannot exist with zero columns. What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE customer_grid_flat` show you?

Comment: Just changing  ALTER to CREATE, in the currently show statement does create a table with a lot of fields.... This makes the question unclear.  It is unknow what the current problem is (besides lack of knowledge)

Comment: Please read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE` needs `ADD COLUMN` and `ADD INDEX`, not what you have.

> The table is created but has nothing in it.. so i'm trying to insert all the columns

That statement is ambiguous.  The first part, "has nothing in it", usually means "no rows".  But if you mean "has no columns", then I recommend you simply `DROP TABLE...` to get rid of the zero-column table you have and simply change `ALTER` to `CREATE` and run that.